# Unable to find Debug SHA 1 Key from new Android Studio 4.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sha1

I am using Android Studio 4.2.1. I am trying to get Debug SHA 1 Key via Studio. I can't find signInReport section, for previous versions it was located in Gradle tab in Sidebar. How can I access signInReport from latest Android Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the steps to get the SHA1 from android studio**

**STEP 1: Click Edit Configurations**

[image]

**STEP 2: Click Gradle**

[image]

**STEP 3: Follow up the Red arrow and choose your project**

[image]

**STEP 4: Type signingreport as per the below image click apply and OK**

[image]

**STEP 5: Run the Process choose signingreport in default and click Run button**

[image]

**STEP 6: Result for the SHA1 Key**

[image]

Comment: Works for the latest android studios as well.